# first middle last name python

Tags: python, indexing

```
# Write a program that asks the user to enter name in  
# 'first middle last' format. THe program should print 
# the name in format 'last,middleinitial first'

name=input('Enter name in [first middle last] format:')
space1= name.index(' ')
first=name[0:space1]

space2=name.index(' ',space1+1)
#mandatory paramenter comes beofre optional parameter

middle=name[space1+1:space2]
last=name[space2+1:]
newname=last+','+ middle[0]+'.'+first
print(new name)
```

HI GUYS! I was just having some trouble understanding the program we wrote in class. I understand how we use index to find space 1 but

- how is this exactly working `space2 = name.index(' ',space1+1)`?

Space `1+1` takes it to one space more than space `1`.

- How does that help in finding space `2`?

APPRECIATE  YOUR HELP!

Comment: What were you doing in the class?  Why not clear your doubts there itself?

Comment: Try printing the variables `space1` and `space2`; it might help.

Comment: Yeah I printed space1 and space2. I just have trouble in this part space2=name.index(' ',space1+1). What is space1+1 doing here? Doesn't index find the first time occurrence only?

Comment: __Please__ read some bit of [documentation](http://docs.python.org).

Comment: done that too! didn't help

Comment: If you look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index), do the *optional* `start` and `end` parameters make any sense? Think about what the value of `space1` is.

Comment: yes i know start end and increment in terms on range. And i also understand it here. When you write index(' ', space1+1) then the end part is (space 1+1)-1 as the end part is not included, so basically it starts from space 1 and ends at space 1. this is what is tricking me

Comment: to all the haters voting down my qs. Just want to say just cause you are 'too' good at something doesn't mean everyone is. So drop dead with the attitude(literally). I don't care. and everyone who tried to help, thanks.

Comment: `index(' ', space1+1)` means find a `' '` whose index >= space1+1, means another space after the first space(yes, the second space).

Comment: but doest space 1+1 just mean one position after space 1. For eg. if space 1 was 4 then space 1+1 is 5. how can 5 be space 2 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`how is this exactly working space2 = name.index(' ',space1+1)?`

That `space1+1` tells the index function to start looking for the position of the second space after the first space (if you wouldn't do that, it would always find you the 1st space, as it always starts searching from the beginning).

eg: `name = 'enie meenie minie'` the first space is found at the position `space1=4`. In order to find the 2nd space you have to start searching from the position after the 1st space (eg.: `space1+1 = 5`), and that would give you `space2=11`.

Comment: ohh i understand. Thanks for explaining. Now i understand what was happening. So it basically functions as a range without the end and ' ' is the thing it is looking for.?

Comment: Close enough: the function `index` is like `find`: you tell it what to search for, and from what position to start searching.

Comment: oak thank you. Have an exam. your explanation will surely help!